# SELECT * in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to do `SELECT *` in SQLAlchemy?

Specifically, `SELECT * WHERE foo=1`?

Comment: If you want the sql rendered explicitly as `select * ...` you can use `select(column('*', _selectable=src), ..)` to generate your query.  This also works in a join see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77267042/2336373

Answer (score 57):

Is no one feeling the ORM love of SQLAlchemy today? The presented answers correctly describe the lower-level interface that SQLAlchemy provides. Just for completeness, this is the more-likely *(for me)* real-world situation where you have a session instance and a User class that is ORM mapped to the `users` table.

```
for user in session.query(User).filter_by(name='jack'):
     print(user)
     # ...
```

And this does an explicit `select` on all columns.

Comment: I think the reason mike asked about `SELECT *` specifically is to get a sequence of column values. A full solution using the ORM would be to get the User objects as above, then find a way of iterating over columns as discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537471/method-of-iterating-over-sqlalchemy-models-defined-columns.

Comment: what if I join two models and want all the resulting columns?

Comment: What if `Select * from` is in a subquery?

Comment: @mattsom you can use select(*subq.c) see my answer below

Comment: This was the answer for me in conjunction with the addition of `__str__` method defined on my table class for printing out the columns to my taste (I only wanted to inspect for sanity check).

Comment: old answer, no longer valid in 1.4

Answer (score 36):

The following selection works for me in the core expression language (returning a [RowProxy object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.RowProxy)):

```
foo_col = sqlalchemy.sql.column('foo')
s = sqlalchemy.sql.select(['*']).where(foo_col == 1)
```

Comment: hmm.. this didn't work for me, but replacing `['*']` with `[sqlalchemy.text('*')]` did.

Comment: How do I jsonify the query `s` result  ?

Answer (score 14):

If you don't list any columns, you get all of them.

```
query = users.select()
query = query.where(users.c.name=='jack')
result = conn.execute(query)
for row in result:
    print row
```

Should work.

Comment: What if I want a WHERE clause?

Comment: @S.Lott that link has expired

Comment: Looks like for me, I get an `OperationalError`.  Leaving out the "where" part, II can see `str(query)` gives `'SELECT  \nFROM trials'`.  It's missing the asterisk

Comment: no longer valid 1.4

Answer (score 11):

You can always use a raw SQL too:

```
str_sql = sql.text("YOUR STRING SQL")
#if you have some args:
args = {
    'myarg1': yourarg1
    'myarg2': yourarg2}
#then call the execute method from your connection
results = conn.execute(str_sql,args).fetchall()
```

Comment: One can but that is not the question.

Answer (score 10):

Where **Bar** is the class mapped to your table and **session** is your sa session:

```
bars = session.query(Bar).filter(Bar.foo == 1)
```

Answer (score 9):

Turns out you can do:

```
sa.select('*', ...)
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, I was trying to get all columns from a table as a list instead of getting ORM objects back. So that I can convert that list to pandas dataframe and display.

What works is to use `.c` on a subquery or cte as follows:

```
U = select(User).cte('U')
stmt = select(*U.c)
rows = session.execute(stmt)
```

Then you get a list of tuples with each column.

Another option is to use `__table__.columns` in the same way:

```
stmt = select(*User.__table__.columns)
rows = session.execute(stmt)
```

In case you want to convert the results to dataframe here is the one liner:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=rows.keys())
```

Answer (score 4):

For joins if columns are not defined manually, only columns of target table are returned. To get all columns for joins(User table joined with Group Table:

```py
sql = User.select(from_obj(Group, User.c.group_id == Group.c.id))
# Add all coumns of Group table to select
sql = sql.column(Group)
session.connection().execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, I was trying to get all columns from a table as a list instead of getting ORM objects back. So that I can convert that list to pandas dataframe and display.

What works is to use `.c` on a subquery or cte as follows:

```
U = select(User).cte('U')
stmt = select(*U.c)
rows = session.execute(stmt)
```

Then you get a list of tuples with each column.

Another option is to use `__table__.columns` in the same way:

```
stmt = select(*User.__table__.columns)
rows = session.execute(stmt)
```

In case you want to convert the results to dataframe here is the one liner:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(dict(zip(r.keys(), r)) for r in rows)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the ORM, you can build a query using the normal ORM constructs and then execute it directly to get raw column values:

```
query = session.query(User).filter_by(name='jack')
for cols in session.connection().execute(query):
    print cols
```

Comment: If you already have a `session` object that you used to get the query, why are you using the connection's `execute`? You can just do - `for user in query: print user.name, user.age`

Answer (score 2):

```py
every_column = User.__table__.columns
records = session.query(*every_column).filter(User.foo==1).all()
```

When a ORM class is passed to the query function, e.g. `query(User)`, the result will be composed of ORM instances. In the majority of cases, this is what the dev wants and will be easiest to deal with--demonstrated by the popularity of the answer above that corresponds to this approach.

In some cases, devs may instead want [an iterable sequence of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636548/select-in-sqlalchemy/70352670#comment17034585_636631). In these cases, one can pass the list of desired column objects to `query()`. This answer shows how to pass the entire list of columns without hardcoding them, while still working with SQLAlchemy at the ORM layer.

Answer (score 0):

As of SQLAlchemy 2.0, one of the ways to do this is passing the name of the object representing the table in the `select` function:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("{DB_dialect}+{DBAPI}://{server}/{database}?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server")
conn = engine.connect()
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
metadata.reflect(bind=engine)
table = metadata.tables["user"]

query = sqlalchemy.select(table).where(table.c.first_name == 'John').where(table.c.last_name == 'Doe')
```

This code creates a trusted connection and a SQL query like:

```
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE first_name = "John" AND last_name = "DOE"
```