# method of iterating over sqlalchemy model's defined columns?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've been trying to figure out how to iterate over the list of columns defined in a SQLAlchemy model. I want it for writing some serialization and copy methods to a couple of models. I can't just iterate over the `obj.__dict__` since it contains a lot of SA specific items.

Anyone know of a way to just get the `id` and `desc` names from the following?

```
class JobStatus(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'jobstatus'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    desc = Column(Unicode(20))
```

In this small case I could easily create a:

```
def logme(self):
    return {'id': self.id, 'desc': self.desc}
```

but I'd prefer something that auto-generates the `dict` (for larger objects).

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You could use the following function:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return "[%s(%s)]" % (self.__class__.__name__, ', '.join('%s=%s' % (k, self.__dict__[k]) for k in sorted(self.__dict__) if '_sa_' != k[:4]))
```

It will exclude SA *magic* attributes, but will not exclude the relations. So basically it might load the dependencies, parents, children etc, which is definitely not desirable.

But it is actually much easier because if you inherit from `Base`, you have a `__table__` attribute, so that you can do:

```
for c in JobStatus.__table__.columns:
    print c

for c in JobStatus.__table__.foreign_keys:
    print c
```

See [How to discover table properties from SQLAlchemy mapped object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441796/how-to-discover-table-properties-from-sqlalchemy-mapped-object/2448930#2448930) - similar question.

**Edit by Mike:** Please see functions such as [Mapper.c](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/mapper_config.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.c) and [Mapper.mapped_table](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/mapper_config.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.mapped_table).  If using 0.8 and higher also see [Mapper.attrs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/mapper_config.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.attrs) and related functions.

Example for [Mapper.attrs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.attrs):

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
mapper = inspect(JobStatus)
for column in mapper.attrs:
    print column.key
```

Comment: Note that `__table__.columns` will give you the SQL field names, not the attribute names that you've used in your ORM definitions (if the two differ).

Comment: Might I recommend changing `'_sa_' != k[:4]` to `not k.startswith('_sa_')`?

Comment: No need to loop with inspect: `inspect(JobStatus).columns.keys()`

Comment: if you set values with `model.__dict__[column]` sqlalchemy does not detect changes.

Comment: If you want to know anything more than the name, you have to use the mapper.attrs approach.  I needed to know the length of a String column and couldn't get it with the regular __table__.column.  I think you should make that its own answer and I'll upvote it

Answer (score 66):

You can get the list of defined properties from the mapper. For your case you're interested in only ColumnProperty objects.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper
import sqlalchemy

def attribute_names(cls):
    return [prop.key for prop in class_mapper(cls).iterate_properties
        if isinstance(prop, sqlalchemy.orm.ColumnProperty)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this let me create a __todict__ method on Base which I then use to 'dump' an instance out to a dict I can then pass through for pylon's jsonify decorator response. 

I tried to put a more details note with code example in my original question but it's causing stackoverflow to error on submission.

Comment: btw, `class_mapper` needs to be imported from `sqlalchemy.orm`

Comment: While this is a legitimate answer, after the version 0.8 it is suggested to use `inspect()`, which returns the exact same mapper object as `class_mapper()`.
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/inspection.html

Comment: This helped me a lot to map SQLAlchemy model property names to the underlying column names.

Answer (score 37):

I realise that this is an old question, but I've just come across the same requirement and would like to offer an alternative solution to future readers.

As Josh notes, full SQL field names will be returned by `JobStatus.__table__.columns`, so rather than the original field name  *id*, you will get *jobstatus.id*. Not as useful as it could be.

The solution to obtaining a list of field names as they were originally defined is to look the `_data` attribute on the column object, which contains the full data. If we look at `JobStatus.__table__.columns._data`, it looks like this:

```
{'desc': Column('desc', Unicode(length=20), table=<jobstatus>),
 'id': Column('id', Integer(), table=<jobstatus>, primary_key=True, nullable=False)}
```

From here you can simply call `JobStatus.__table__.columns.keys()` which gives you a nice, clean list:

```
['id', 'desc']
```

Comment: Nice! Is there a way with this method to get at relationships as well?

Comment: there is no need for _data attr, just ..columns.keys() do the trick

Comment: Yes, using the private _data attribute should be avoided where possible, @Humoyun is more correct.

Comment: AttributeError: __data

Comment: I'd also like to retrieve the relationships

Answer (score 23):

Assuming you're using SQLAlchemy's declarative mapping, you can use `__mapper__` attribute to get at the class mapper. To get all mapped attributes (including relationships):

```
obj.__mapper__.attrs.keys()
```

If you want strictly column names, use `obj.__mapper__.column_attrs.keys()`. See the documentation for other views.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.attrs

Comment: This is the simple answer.

Answer (score 15):

`self.__table__.columns` will "only" give you the columns defined in that particular class, i.e. without inherited ones.  if you need all, use `self.__mapper__.columns`.  in your example i'd probably use something like this:

```
class JobStatus(Base):

    ...

    def __iter__(self):
        values = vars(self)
        for attr in self.__mapper__.columns.keys():
            if attr in values:
                yield attr, values[attr]

    def logme(self):
        return dict(self)
```

Answer (score 11):

To get an `as_dict` method on all of my classes I used a `Mixin` class which uses the technics described by [Ants Aasma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107366/ants-aasma).

```
class BaseMixin(object):                                                                                                                                                                             
    def as_dict(self):                                                                                                                                                                               
        result = {}                                                                                                                                                                                  
        for prop in class_mapper(self.__class__).iterate_properties:                                                                                                                                 
            if isinstance(prop, ColumnProperty):                                                                                                                                                     
                result[prop.key] = getattr(self, prop.key)                                                                                                                                           
        return result
```

And then use it like this in your classes

```
class MyClass(BaseMixin, Base):
    pass
```

That way you can invoke the following on an instance of `MyClass`.

```
> myclass = MyClass()
> myclass.as_dict()
```

Hope this helps.

---

I've played arround with this a bit further, I actually needed to render my instances as `dict` as the form of a [HAL object](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) with it's links to related objects. So I've added this little magic down here, which will crawl over all properties of the class same as the above, with the difference that I will crawl deeper into `Relaionship` properties and generate `links` for these automatically.

***Please note that this will only work for relationships have a single primary key***

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper, ColumnProperty
from functools import reduce


def deepgetattr(obj, attr):
    """Recurses through an attribute chain to get the ultimate value."""
    return reduce(getattr, attr.split('.'), obj)


class BaseMixin(object):
    def as_dict(self):
        IgnoreInstrumented = (
            InstrumentedList, InstrumentedDict, InstrumentedSet
        )
        result = {}
        for prop in class_mapper(self.__class__).iterate_properties:
            if isinstance(getattr(self, prop.key), IgnoreInstrumented):
                # All reverse relations are assigned to each related instances
                # we don't need to link these, so we skip
                continue
            if isinstance(prop, ColumnProperty):
                # Add simple property to the dictionary with its value
                result[prop.key] = getattr(self, prop.key)
            if isinstance(prop, RelationshipProperty):
                # Construct links relaions
                if 'links' not in result:
                    result['links'] = {}

                # Get value using nested class keys
                value = (
                    deepgetattr(
                        self, prop.key + "." + prop.mapper.primary_key[0].key
                    )
                )
                result['links'][prop.key] = {}
                result['links'][prop.key]['href'] = (
                    "/{}/{}".format(prop.key, value)
                )
        return result
```

Comment: Please add `from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper, ColumnProperty` on top of your code snippet

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've added the missing imports

Comment: It's the declarative Base of sqlalchemy read more on that here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/basic_use.html

Answer (score 2):

```
self.__dict__
```

returns a dict where keys are attribute names and values the values of the object.

/!\ there is a supplementary attribute: '_sa_instance_state'
but you can handle it :)

Comment: Only when attributes are set.

Answer (score 2):

While `row._asdict()` worked for most of the cases, I needed some approach that also works after object creation process (`db.session.add` etc.). The idea is to create a method `to_dict` accessing columns on the table object and use standard `getattr`.

```py
class Inventory(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'inventory'

    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column('date', db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    item = db.Column('item', db.String(100))

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            column.name: getattr(self, column.name, None)
            for column in Inventory.__table__.columns
        }



record = Inventory(item="gloves")
db.session.add(record)
db.session.commit()

# print(record._asdict()) # << that doesn't work
print(record.to_dict()) # << that works as intended
```

This solution will produce dict with columns only - no meta attributes or anything that you will have to manually clean after the next major update (if any).

PS. I use flask-sqlalchemy but it does not change the idea

Answer (score 0):

I want to get the data of a particular instance of Model dynamically. I used this code.

```
def to_json(instance):
    # get columns data
    data = {}
    columns = list(instance.__table__.columns)
    for column in columns:
        data[column.name] = instance.__dict__[column.name]
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

To map a model from sqlalchemy to a json, taking into account relationships, I use this code

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeclarativeMeta
from sqlalchemy.orm import ColumnProperty
from sqlalchemy.orm import RelationshipProperty


class BaseMixin(object):
    """BaseMixin"""

    __repr_hide = ["created_at", "updated_at"]
    __insert_hide = []

    @property
    def _repr_hide(self):
        return self.__repr_hide

    @_repr_hide.setter
    def _repr_hide(self, k):
        self.__repr_hide.append(k)

    @property
    def _insert_hide(self):
        return self.__insert_hide

    @_insert_hide.setter
    def _insert_hide(self, k):
        self.__insert_hide.append(k)

    def serialize(self, obj):
        """serialize from json"""
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if k in self.__repr_hide:
                continue
            if k in self.__insert_hide:
                continue
            if k in self.__table__.c.keys():
                setattr(self, k, v)
        return self

    def deserialize(self, backref=None):
        """deserialize to json"""
        res = dict()

        for prop in class_mapper(self.__class__).iterate_properties:
            if prop.key in self.__repr_hide:
                continue
            if isinstance(prop, ColumnProperty):
                res[prop.key] = getattr(self, prop.key)

        for prop in class_mapper(self.__class__).iterate_properties:
            if prop.key in self.__repr_hide:
                continue
            if isinstance(prop, RelationshipProperty):
                if prop.key == str(backref):
                    continue
                key, value = prop.key, getattr(self, prop.key)
                if value is None:
                    res[key] = None
                elif isinstance(value.__class__, DeclarativeMeta):
                    res[key] = value.deserialize(backref=self.__table__)
                else:
                    res[key] = [i.deserialize(backref=self.__table__) for i in value]
        return res

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.deserialize().items())

    def __repr__(self):
        vals = ", ".join(
            "%s=%r" % (n, getattr(self, n))
            for n in self.__table__.c.keys()
            if n not in self._repr_hide
        )

        return "<%s={%s}>" % (self.__class__.__name__, vals)
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question, but what about:

```
class JobStatus(Base):

    ...

    def columns(self):
        return [col for col in dir(self) if isinstance(col, db.Column)]
```

Then, to get column names: `jobStatus.columns()`

That would return `['id', 'desc']`

Then you can loop through, and do stuff with the columns and values:

```
for col in jobStatus.colums():
    doStuff(getattr(jobStatus, col))
```

Comment: you cannot do isinstance(col, Column) on a string

Comment: Downvoted because __table__.columns and __mapper__.columns give you this data without re-inventing the wheel.