# Registering star SELECT (*) @compiles for mapped class entities in a sqlalchemy ORM query

Tags: python, python-3.x, orm, sqlalchemy

so I have a requirement to replace the individual column select that `sqlalchemy` automatically does in its queries with a general star select (`SELECT table.* FROM...`) whenever the whole table or mapped class is provided to `Session.query()`. It shouldn't change how `InstrumentedAttribute` objects are compiled though.

So for example, for the ORM classes `Table1` and `Table2`:

```py
str(s.query(Table1, Table2.col1, Table2.col2).select_from(Table1).join(Table2))
```

Should display as:

```sql
SELECT table1.*, table2.col1, table2.col2
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.some_col = table2.some_other_col
```

I've read the `sqlalchemy` documentation on the `@compiles` decorator factory and I've tried to use it on the following expression constructs with a simple breakpoint:

```py
sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnCollection
sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ClauseList
sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement
sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TableClause
```

so for example:

```py
@compiles(sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnCollection)
def star_select(element, compiler, **kwargs):
    breakpoint()
```

but no matter which of these I pass to `@compiles`, the flow of execution never actually goes into the function I've decorated with `@compiles`. And I can't find any others that would seem to do what I want.

Does anyone have any idea which `sqlalchemy` class I'd have to pass to the @compiles function to override just the column select list portion of an ORM select query?

I'm feel like I'm going crazy with this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why such a requirement? Using `*` in other than ad-hoc / manual queries is usually frowned upon.

Comment: It's because the actual sql written by the ORM has to be logged in a script for other team members to be able to later go back to if needed. And there are some queries with a truly grotesque number of columns per table, where it takes away from the legibility a lot to have them explicitly named. Also, it keeps consistency with other team members that aren't using python to automate this. All the manually written queries use select star syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I was fooling with this as well.  It doesn't seem very well documented but you can use a `column('*')` to get your `select *` and set the `_selectable` to say it's coming from `table1.  So you can write something like this which gets rendered as you want:

```
select(
    column('*', _selectable=table1), 
    table2.c.col1,
    table2.c.col2
).join(
    table2, 
    table1.c.some_col == table2.c.some_other_col
)
```

Comment: unfortunately this only works at the end of a query, it loses track of the specific column names from table1, with the result columns object containing `['*', 'col1', 'col2']`